# Как измененить атрибут доступа к файлу кроссплатформенно?

Tags: кроссплатформенность, boost, c++

Для работы с файловой системой используется `boost::filesystem`, в том числе и для удаления файлов. Но вот что не получается: удалить файл, если он имеет атрибут "только для чтения", так что приходится его сбрасывать ОС-специфическим образом (на Windows это `SetFileAttributes()`). Как можно изменить этот атрибут кроссплатформенным образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать _chmod для Windows и chmod для Unix и собирать по отдельности для Windows и Unix:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <io.h>
#define SKIP_READ_ONLY(...) _chmod(...)
#else
#define SKIP_READ_ONLY(...)  chmod(...)
#endif
```

Comment: В MinGW в винде chmod() тоже работает. В этом случае можно без условной компиляции (достаточно sys/stat.h).

Answer (score 2):

boost::filesystem не предоставляет такой возможности.
Выдержка из [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/faq.htm):

> Because access to many other attributes is inherently system dependent, property maps are viewed as the best hope for access and modification, but it is better design to provide such functionality in a separate library. (Historical note: even the apparently simple attribute **"read-only"** turned out to be so **system depend** as to be disqualified as a "guaranteed presence" operation.)

**UPD**
Нашел подходящую библиотеку [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/index.html), с её помощью можно делать так:

```
#include <Poco/File.h>

using namespace Poco;

int main() {
    File f("foo");
    f.setReadOnly();
    return 0;
}
```

Сам никогде не пользовался.

Comment: Спасибо, @gkuznets. Вот я испрашиваю: есть ли какой либо другой способ (может, даже другая библиотека), с помощью которой можно решить эту задачу, не прибегая к явным API-вызовам?